# Check if timestamp is today

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I've got a timestamp in the following format (Which can easily be changed thanks to the beauties of PHP!).

> 2011-02-12 14:44:00

What is the quickest/simplest way to check if this timestamp was taken today?

Comment: do you mean "on this day" or within the last 24 hours?

Comment: @Mark This might help http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/today ;)

Comment: definition of today: "this day"

Comment: @Mark so when someone expects you to go to the shop today, they might have a surprise...

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I think:

```
date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($timestamp))
```

Comment: i think check equal between 2 integer is better than 2 string

Comment: @Davood I'd be curious to know why.

Comment: 1. if case sensitive of 2 string be diffrent, return false, 2. for php optimization check equal between 2 integer is more optimal between 2 string . this is my idea .

Comment: Technically, they're both strings. They will be evaluated as two integers though (PHP is crazy). In thise case that doesn't matter, because both sides are 8 characters (digits) long and none start with 0. If either were false, you'd have to use `===`.

Comment: @Davood You're explicitly creating two strings of the format `Y-m-d` there, no case sensitivity problems possible. Maybe two integers are faster to compare, but you'll have to convert both into an integer before you can compare them, which is more overhead than comparing two strings directly.

Comment: @deceze In this case (`'20110212'` and `==`), they will be evaluated as integers, though, right? What's the difference between that and numerical or lexical? (Serious question) Did you know that `"5" == "5.0"`? I think that's silly!

Comment: I love this article (it's about Javascript, but it's relevant): http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: @Rudie Sorry, I have to retract that statement. Numerical strings *are* actually converted to numbers. So my only quip can be that they're converted to *numbers*, not *integers*. ;-P

Comment: @Davood: the Y-m-d format returns a purely numeric date components, e.g. 2011-05-03. There is not case sensitivity with numbers, even if the comparison is done on a string basis.

Comment: @Marc B, It's Correct, what is your idea about : (int)date('Ymd') == (int)date('Ymd', strtotime($timestamp))

Comment: @Davood: doing (int) like that will destroy the comparison, as you'll only get the year value out. Either cast/compare the individual components as integers, or compare the whole thing as a string. Anything else will be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2011-02-12 14:44:00'))) {
    // is today
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$offset = date('Z'); //timezone offset in seconds

if (floor(($UNIX_TIMESTAMP + $offset) / 86400) == floor((mktime(0,0,0) + $offset) / 86400)){
    echo "today";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for this kind of task :

```
/** date comparator restricted by $format.
 @param {int/string/Datetime} $timeA
 @param {int/string/Datetime} $timeB
 @param {string} $format
 @returns : 0 if same. 1 if $timeA before $timeB. -1 if after   */
function compareDates($timeA,$timeB,$format){
    $dateA=$timeA instanceof Datetime?$timeA:(is_numeric($timeA)?(new \Datetime())->setTimestamp($timeA):(new \Datetime("".$timeA)));
    $dateB=$timeB instanceof Datetime?$timeB:(is_numeric($timeB)?(new \Datetime())->setTimestamp($timeB):(new \Datetime("".$timeB)));
    return $dateA->format($format)==$dateB->format($format)?0:($dateA->getTimestamp()<$dateB->getTimestamp()?1:-1);
}
```

compare day : **$format**='Y-m-d'.
  compare month : **$format**='Y-m'.
  etc...

in your case :

```
if(compareDates("now",'2011-02-12 14:44:00','Y-m-d')===0){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to compare timestamps (rather then date strings), so I use this to check today.

```
$dayString = "2011-02-12 14:44:00";
$dayStringSub = substr($dayString, 0, 10);

$isToday = ( strtotime('now') >= strtotime($dayStringSub . " 00:00") 
          && strtotime('now') <  strtotime($dayStringSub . " 23:59") );
```

Fiddle: http://ideone.com/55JBku

Comment: Some explanation about your answer would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
(date('Ymd') == gmdate('Ymd', $db['time']) ? 'today' : '')
```

Answer (score -1):

are you mean this ?

```
if( strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' , strtotime( '2011-02-12 14:44:00' ) ) ) == strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) )
{
//IS TODAY;
}
```

Comment: why ? i think it's more better !

Comment: It's more better..? Sure... but it's still a waste of date calculations. Without the 2 `strtotime`'s, you know enough to make the evaluation.

Comment: Furthermore, this *may* result in incorrect values. UNIX timestamps are seconds and `strtotime` fills in any information that's not in the given date string from the current time. I.e. the hours, minutes and seconds part of `strtotime('2011-02-12')` will be taken from the current time. In the rare circumstance that the time advances by one second between the first call to `strtotime` and the second, you may get two different timestamps for the same day.