# How to check if a previously stored time() value is today in php?

Tags: php, linux

How to check if a previously stored time() value is today in php?

I have a xml stored with a timestamp generated from time() in php. I would like to use php to check if the date of the timestamp is today. Whats the best way to do this? I'm very confused on the format of PHP date/time functions. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if timestamp is today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775076/check-if-timestamp-is-today)

Comment: Convert the stored timestamp and the current timestamp to dates, and check if they match?

Comment: Basically `date('Ymd') === date('Ymd', $timestamp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$timestamp = yourprevioustimestamp;
if(date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', $timestamp)){
//if it's equal...
}
else{
//if it is not...
}
```