# How to check if timestamp is after today midnight?

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I tried to check if timestamp is from today (after midnight).

For example, this is the timestamp that I want to check: `1572122130`.

What I tried:

```
<?php

$time = strtotime('today midnight') - 1572122130;

if($time < 86400){
    echo "timestamp is from today!"; //timestamp is from today (after midnight)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate [check-if-timestamp-is-today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775076/check-if-timestamp-is-today)

Comment: @jibsteroos The duplicate tells how to check the date part is today, not whether the timestamp is today or later. I feel like it is a small difference, but significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for this.

```
$ts = 1572122130;

$today = (new \DateTime())->setTime(0, 0); // get tonight midnight

// compare the timestamp to the date above
var_dump(date_create_from_format('U', $ts) >= $today);
```